# Python Error in Reading Files using Aiofiles

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles

Simple Problem statement. I want to read files asynchronously . My problem is when I try to read a file using aiofiles.open it just errors out with the cryptic messsage

```
AttributeError: __enter_
```

The crux of the problem can be demonstrated with the following sample

```
with open("/tmp/test/abc_20211105.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("this is a sample!")
with aiofiles.open('/tmp/test/abc_20211105.txt','r') as f: # This is where the error occurs
    f.read()
```

the file gets created but I can't read the same file using aiofiles.

I have tried specifying encoding etc, but nothing helps.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aiofiles.open` context manager is meant to be used asynchronously (`async with`), in a coroutine. Standard synchronous context managers rely on `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, while `async` context managers use methods named `__aenter__` and `__aexit__`, thus, `async with` is necessary to call the `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods of `aiofiles.open`, instead of `__enter__` and `__exit__` (which are not defined for `aiofiles.open`):

```
import asyncio
async def read_files():
   async with aiofiles.open('/tmp/test/abc_20211105.txt','r') as f:
      await f.read() 

asyncio.run(read_files())
```